# Can't build project using Qt in VSC

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I have a `Cmake` project that runs in `QtCreator` without a problem. When running the same project outside QtCreator (i.e. `cmake ..`) I get:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Hector-2:build hectoresteban$ cmake ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

My original `CMakeFile` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(trial LANGUAGES C CXX)
set(ANDROID_NDK_ROOT "/Users/hectoresteban/Documents/C++/Qt/android-ndk-r21d")

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets LinguistTools REQUIRED)
```

Which in `QtCreator` when building using

```
Running /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.3/bin/cmake '-GUnix Makefiles' /Users/hectoresteban/Documents/C++/Qt/trial in /Users/hectoresteban/Documents/C++/Qt/build-trial-Desktop_x86_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit-Debug.
```

works totally fine. To build from terminal I have tried to do:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/Users/hectoresteban/Qt")
```

but still same issue. My `/Users/hectoresteban/Qt` folder looks like:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally those `5.x.x` directories should contain a `lib/cmake` directory.
Set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to that.

Comment: Inside 5.x.x there are other folders and for example in clang_64 there is a lib/cmake but in wasm32 as well. Which one do I choose?

Comment: That depends on which platform you want to target. Your CMake file contained references to the Android NDK so I'm guessing you want the `android` one? (`clang_64` would be a macOS executable, `wasm_32` something to run on the web)